# Crontab: dangling hyphens

Tags: cron

In `crontab` you can specify ranges using hyphens (e. g. "0-15").

But recently I've seen an entry like this:

```
-*/15 * * * * command
```

What does hyphen plus an asterisk mean in this entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argh, looks like it's an extension. Should've read this `man` page until the end.

> *If the uid of the owner is 0 (root), he can put a "-" as first character of a crontab entry. This will prevent cron from writing a syslog  message about this command getting executed.*

Comment: What version of `cron`? What distribution?

Comment: @Dennis Williamson, ISC cron 4.1